# Getting max possible value of integer data type in Octave

Tags: range, octave

I use `GNU Octave, version 6.4.0`. Is there any command for getting size of usual data classes, at least for integral data types? Really I want to get max possible value for data type of a matrix which is related to an image. For example for an `uint8` image such `I` it must return `256` for argument `class(I)`. I am looking for a builtin command and do not want to write a `switch` myself.

Comment: see the `intmax()` function. Either `intmax("uint8")` or `a=uint8(1); intmax(a)`. Similarly there is is `realmax()` function.

Comment: Note that this is not the "size of range" neither the "size" but the maximum representable value for the type. Please update your title and text to be more accurate.

Comment: @PierU Thank you, please add your comment as answer, so I can accept it. That may be useful for others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `intmax()` function does what you want for integer types. Either `intmax("uint8")` or `intmax(a)` where `a` is of type `uint8` (or any other integer type).

https://octave.sourceforge.io/octave/function/intmax.html

A similar function `realmax()` exists for floating point types.